# WSO2 Identity Server (wso2is-5.11.0) - Is it possible to bulk import users to secondary userstores?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2is-5.11.0 and there's a requirement to bulk import users into a secondary userstore. However, when I try it using the carbon console, the dropdown menu only shows the primary userstore.
Is it possible to bulk import users into a secondary userstore?
Thanks in advance.

[image: Dropdown menu only displays the primary userstore]

Comment: According to the [guide](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-lifecycles/bulk-import-users/), you will be able to bulk import only to the PRIMARY userstore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is an issue with the property name set in the secondary userstores which used to indicate bulk user import feature supporting.

1. Go to `<IS-HOME>/repository/deployment/server/userstores`
2. You can see the XML file for the secondary userstore that you have created.
3. You will see a property as `<Property name="BulkImportSupported">true</Property>`
4. Change the property name as follows.
   `<Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">true</Property>`

Then you can see the secondary userstore in bulk import feature drop-down.
[image]

If you select the secondary userstore and add the csv file, users will be
imported to the secondary userstore.